# In what ways will the Windows 8 RTM build differ from the release preview

Tags: windows-8-preview

In a nutshell, In what ways will the Windows 8 RTM build differ from the release preview?

I've being using the Windows 8 Release Preview almost exclusively over the past few months (and the developer and consumer previews before that) and it has really grow on me.

Have the Windows 8 team released details on how the final build will differ from the most recent preview?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lack of a time bomb, for one thing. (By time bomb I mean eventually the release preview will expire.)

Ongoing hotfix support - I'd expect that to be pretty limited for the release preview after Windows 8 ships.

More bug fixes - any last minute fixes or changes they need to make to ensure it's as stable and correct as possible.

In theory, that should be about it, but stuff happens and you never know.